# Create a new image every time user takes a new photo in firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In my app user presses the button to take the photo and then it uploads to firebase storage but every time I do a new photo the old one disappears and it replaces itself with the same url string as old one had before. How can I upload a new image every time the same user takes and uploads the photo?

Here is the code

```
let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    guard  let imageData = ecoImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else {
        return
    }
    
    
        
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    
    
    
        
        storage.child("pins/\("Eco1")").putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { (meta, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                storage.child("pins/\("Eco1")").downloadURL { (url, err) in
                    if let e = err {
                        print(e.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        let urlString = url?.absoluteString
                        doc.setData(["uid": uid, "pinLocation": ecoPin, "time": timeData, "url": urlString!]) { (error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                                return
                            } else {
                                print("Pin saved")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
             print("Image sent")
        }
```

Comment: Use a different path for each upload?

Comment: you use the same name/path each time, so its over writing the previous file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the random file name for every time you put the new photo.
In the code you provided, after the metadata, declare the variable with UUID.

```
let fname = UUID.init().uuidString.replacingOccurences(of: "-", with: "")

storage.child("pins/\(fname))...so on
```

This will generate the random file name each time you upload, and supposedly not replace your previous photo.